# Error in run phalcon framework after create project

Tags: php, phalcon

excuse me, I see the following error when executing the phalcon framework

```
PalconShenaiaController handler class cannot be loaded
#0 [internal function]: Phalcon\Mvc\Dispatcher->throwDispatchException('PalconShenaiaCo...', 2)
#1 [internal function]: Phalcon\Dispatcher\AbstractDispatcher->dispatch()
#2 C:\xampp1\htdocs\palcon_shenaia\public\index.php(43): Phalcon\Mvc\Application->handle('/palcon_shenaia...')
#3 {main}
```

Comment: Please start with the [tour] and read [ask]. Please also note that you're not asking a question even! For many problems, it is also mandatory to first extract a [mcve] and include that inline in your question.

Answer (score 2):

change this line in `/public/index.php`

```php
echo $application->handle($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])->getContent();
```

to

```php
echo $application->handle($_GET['_url'] ?? '/')->getContent();
```

also change `baseUri` in `/app/config/config.php` to

```php
preg_replace('/public([\/\\\\])index.php$/', '', $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"])
```